# GetMessageW is blocking the calling thread, receiving no messages

Tags: c, windows, winapi, rust

I've been struggling with this for a day now and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I'm coding in Rust but this is more of a Windows' api related problem.

```
// first, I'm installing a keyboard hook for the current thread
let hook = SetWindowsHookExW(
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
    Some(low_level_keyboard_proc), // just forwards the call with CallNextHookEx
    ptr::null_mut(),
    0,
);

assert!(!hook.is_null(), "Failed to install the hook");

let mut message: MSG = mem::zeroed();
GetMessageW(&mut message, ptr::null_mut(), 0, 0);

// The GetMessageW function is known to block the calling thread until a new message is sent.
// The thing is: my `low_level_keyboard_proc` handle *does get* called, so I know events are being received.
// I don't understand why the GetMessageW function never returns even though events are being processed.
// Note that my handler does not get called when I remove the GetMessageW function.

println!("Unreachable code...");

UnhookWindowsHook(hook);
```

I tried to use the [`PeekMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew) function instead but the problem is the same: the function always return `FALSE` (no events received) even though the handler is getting properly called.

If I remove the [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) part, [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew) is still blocking the thread *BUT* if I remove the [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew) part and put an infinite loop it its place, the handler does not get called anymore.

... so here is the question: **why does the [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew) function never return?** And **if this behaviour is normal, how am I supposed to use the message that I provide to [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew).**

I'm assuming I don't understand well the relationship between [`GetMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagew) and [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).

**EDIT:** I understand that I can't catch the messages sent to the keyboard hook I created. Now, what would the "right" way to retrieve keyboard messages look like? Because it would be real handy to be able to get those messages directly from the message loop instead of having to send them back from the callback function to my main code using static structures.

I'm trying to create an event loop that can be used regardless of a context or the focus of a window. The idea is retrieving those messages directly from a message loop and dispatch them using a user-defined custom handler that can be used through safe rust code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no window messages or thread messages being posted to the message queue of the thread that is installing the keyboard hook, so there are no messages for `GetMessageW()` to return TO YOU.

However, `SetWindowsHookEx()` uses its own messages internally when a low-level keyboard hook crosses thread/process boundaries.  That is why you don't need to implement your hook in a DLL when hooking other applications.  When a keyboard action occurs, a private message is sent TO THE SYSTEM targeting the thread that installed the hook.

That is why the installing thread needs a message loop.  The simple act of performing message retrieval in your code is enough to get those internal messages dispatched properly, which is why your callback function is being  called.  You just won't see those private messages, which is why `GetMessageW()` blocks your code.

The same thing happens when you `SendMessage()` to a window across thread boundaries.  The receiving thread needs a message loop in order for the message to be dispatched to the target window, even though the message doesn't go through the receiving thread's message queue.  This is described in the [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagew) documentation:

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. **Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code.**

So, what happens with `SetWindowsHookEx()` is that it creates a hidden window for itself to receive its private messages, sent via `SendMessage()`, when keyboard activity is detected in a different thread/process and needs to be marshaled back to your installing thread.  This is described in the [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) documentation:

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. **The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook.** Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

Comment: That's actually super interesting. So does this mean I should create my own hidden window (with CreateWindowEx for example) to receive the messages? Or is there a way to catch those messages sent to the system?

Comment: @Gymore creating your own window won't get you access to messages sent to another window. A `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook *might* be able to see the messages (I haven't tried). But they are private to the hook's implementation, why are you trying to access them at all? You don't need them, you can't do anything meaningful with them. So just leave them alone and move on.

Comment: I misspoke. What I wanted to say is that I wanted to use the messages sent to my own Window, the one I would've created. All ideas aside, the real question is "How do I get Windows to send me messages? Maybe using a keyboard hook was not a good idea in the first place. I am editing my original question to make it more precise.

Comment: @Gymore if you create your own window, then you will have to assign it your own WndProc to receive messages with. If you are just looking for the OS to send any messages to it, you could use `SetTimer()`, for instance. But if you are looking for keyboard messages specifically, there are `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` messages when your window has input focus. But to capture keyboard events when you don't have focus, you have to use `SetWindowsHookEx()`, or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to receive `WM_INPUT` messages. It is really not clear what you are trying to accomplish exactly. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Ho, you're right, now that I read my post again, I see that my intentions aren't that clear. I'm editing the post again x)
I'm trying to create an minimal implementation of an event loop (for both keyboard and mouse events) that works regardless of the focus of a window or a context.

Comment: @Gymore "*that works regardless of the focus of a window*" - then you have to use a global keyboard/mouse hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()`, AFAIK there is no other option in user mode. Otherwise, you would have to write custom kernel drivers.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for your time!